# how to checked only one in one row checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, checkbox

how to checked only one in one-row checkbox using javascript

here is my view

```
<?php $c=0; for($a=0; $a < 5; $a++) { ?>
<table>
<tr class="cbclass">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbname" value="1" id="cb" class="cb"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="f_nilai1[]" id="id_tnilai<?php echo $c++; ?>" ></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbname" value="1" id="cb" class="cb"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="f_nilai2[]" id="id_tnilai<?php echo $c++; ?>" ></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbname" value="1" id="cb" class="cb"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="f_nilai3[]" id="id_tnilai<?php echo $c++; ?>"></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbname" value="1" id="cb" class="cb"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="f_nilai4[]" id="id_tnilai<?php echo $c++; ?>"></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="cbname" value="1" id="cb" class="cb"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="f_nilai5[]" id="id_tnilai<?php echo $c++; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

this is my javascript
I have already changed value in input text when the checkbox is clicked, I use it because in insert_batch checkbox not post when null so I use input text to post it, and it's running well. next, is I want only checked in one row, can anybody help me??

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var a = $(".cb").length;              
  $(".cb").click(function(event)
  {
    for(var i=0; i<a; i++) {
     var check = document.getElementsByName('cbname');
         if(check[i].checked) 
        {
      $("#id_tnilai"+[i]).val(1);
      } else {
      $("#id_tnilai"+[i]).val(0);
      }
     }
                          
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the silblings of the current checkbox and change the checked property of those silbilings to none. Code given below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var a = $(".cb").length;                                            
  $(".cb").click(function(event)
  {
    var siblings = $(this).parent().siblings();
    for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
        $(siblings[i]).children().filter('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked','');
    }
    for(var i=0; i<a; i++) {
        var check = document.getElementsByName('cbname');
            if(check[i].checked) 
        {
            $("#id_tnilai"+[i]).val(1);
            } else {
            $("#id_tnilai"+[i]).val(0);
            }
        }

   });
});
</script>
```

Hope this will solve your problem. Thank you

Comment: thanks alot its work for me, one more question please.... how to change background color of element < tr class=cbclass> (only one row) into 'red' if value f_nilai2[ ] ==1, i try many times but its failed